# tables used by spring security?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm developing a web application using spring MVC for users management , and now I want to add a security layer by using `spring security`

for managing users I have this table ùser`in my database :

```
id
name
email
role
contact
```

i've tried to add `login` and `password` column to the previous table and change the sql statement :

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>

    <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="select login,password,enabled from user where login=? "
            authorities-by-username-query="select login,role from user  where login =?  " />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

but the authentication failed  !

I want to ask if there is a specific schema of tables used by `spring security` because all the tutorials I've seen, use a table for `user_id , login , password`and an other for authorities `user_id , enabled`

is it possible to use one table containing all information about  users and their login and password ?

**PS** : I'm using `hibernate` to add, delete users , does this has influence on the authentication ?

Sorry for this question but I'm new to this framework .

Comment: Implement custom `UserDetailsService` and use whatever db schema you want.

Comment: thanks for your reply , do hibernate used for managing users have any influence on authentication via `UserDetailsService` with `jdbc` for example  ? 
is it a good practice for development  or I should use hibernate ?

Comment: Whatever suits your needs. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) 
I will try to code this and I will post the answer .